# Generate oracle sql script to get all data from table

Tags: oracle, plsql

How get all data and **all column** from table some like this.

```
Select  1 as id, 1 as name, .... from dual  --first row
union all
Select  2 as id, 2 as name, .... from dual  --second row
...
union all
Select  199 as id, 199 as name, .... from dual  --last row
```

**as one string**

Input parameter is table_name,  **this is only for small table like continent, country, city....**

Comment: `select * from table_name`?

Comment: @astentx   I need result as one string  row by row with union all

Comment: Please post your current code and describe what is the issue with it. You need to use concatenation operator (`||`) and `listagg` function, but for large table (more that 1000 rows) you'll face ORA-01489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes, you can do that, but:

- what if table contains 100 million rows? You'll NEVER (virtually) "export" nor load data that way.
- Furthermore, it is a simple task to do that with simple datatypes, such as `NUMBERS`. Strings (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`) already require single quotes, but OK, no problem. `DATES` - apart from single quotes, might need to be properly formatted. Time component? Not to mention e.g. `BLOB` columns.
- what kind of (PL/)SQL program should that be? A function? What datatype will it return? `CLOB`? Refcursor? Will it be pipelined? Don't do it with `DBMS_OUTPUT`!

To cut a long story short: use utility which is designed for such a purpose, and that's **Data Pump** (export and import).

---

Why reinventing the wheel? If you don't already use some GUI tool to access your Oracle database, download and install Oracle SQL Developer (it is a free tool).

Establish connection, right-click source table and choose the "Export" option; set parameters to e.g.

[image]

Finish all Wizard steps (basically, just click NEXT) and the result is saved into a file in designed folder and looks like

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  File created - ponedjeljak-lipnja-19-2023   
--------------------------------------------------------
REM INSERTING into SCOTT.DEPT
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into SCOTT.DEPT (DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC) values ('10','ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');
Insert into SCOTT.DEPT (DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC) values ('20','RESEARCH','DALLAS');
Insert into SCOTT.DEPT (DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC) values ('30','SALES','CHICAGO');
Insert into SCOTT.DEPT (DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC) values ('40','OPERATIONS','BOSTON');
```

Comment: This is for small table 100-200 row  to copy data from one to second scheme, only for small table like country, city, continent......